# Export Public Key and Private Key from EC_KEY OpenSSL into SecKeyRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, openssl, keychain

I want to export Public Key and Private Key from `EC_KEY` which is created from OpenSSL and as we know `EC_KEY` hold keypair but openssl is not compatible to store keypair into secure enclave. So I want to Create a certificate from OpenSSL and create keypair from there too and then export keys from `EC_KEY` into SecKeyRef and then create keypair and store in Secure Enclave.

- So above all story first is this possible?
- If yes then how can I export Private Public Key from `EC_KEY` and convert them into SecRefKey
- If I'm wrong on approach then guide me better one

I done First part created certificate from eliptic curve `EC_KEY` from OpenSSL and also done last part to create Keypair too. Here below code for creating Keypair.

```
- (void)generateKeyPair:(NSUInteger)keySize {
OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
publicKey = NULL;
privateKey = NULL;

//  LOGGING_FACILITY1( keySize == 512 || keySize == 1024 || keySize == 2048, @"%d is an invalid and unsupported key size.", keySize );

// First delete current keys.
//  [self deleteAsymmetricKeys];

// Container dictionaries.
NSMutableDictionary * privateKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary * publicKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary * keyPairAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Set top level dictionary for the keypair.
[keyPairAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeEC forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[keyPairAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:keySize] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits];

   [keyPairAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrTokenID forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave];
//    [keyPairAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrTokenID forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave];

// Set the private key dictionary.
[privateKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
[privateKeyAttr setObject:privateTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];

// See SecKey.h to set other flag values.

// Set the public key dictionary.
[publicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
[publicKeyAttr setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
// See SecKey.h to set other flag values.

// Set attributes to top level dictionary.
[keyPairAttr setObject:privateKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs];
[keyPairAttr setObject:publicKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPublicKeyAttrs];

// SecKeyGeneratePair returns the SecKeyRefs just for educational purposes.
sanityCheck = SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyPairAttr, &publicKey, &privateKey);

//  LOGGING_FACILITY( sanityCheck == noErr && publicKey != NULL && privateKey != NULL, @"Something really bad went wrong with generating the key pair." );
if(sanityCheck == noErr  && publicKey != NULL && privateKey != NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"Successful");
}

//  [privateKeyAttr release];
//  [publicKeyAttr release];
//  [keyPairAttr release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import anything the secure enclave. You can only generate a keypair using `SecKeyGeneratePair` (as you did in your code)

Here's the reference to this in Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/keychain_services/token_id_values

Once you have it generated you can either:

- sign data (`SecKeyRawSign`)
- verify signature (`SecKeyRawVerify`)
- encrypt/decrypt (`SecKeyCreateEncryptedData`,`SecKeyCreateDecryptedData`)
- get the keys out (`SecItemCopyMatching`) and do whatever you want with them

If you want interop with OpenSSL you just need to convert them to something OpenSSL can read (e.g. PEM, DER, etc)

Here's a simple conversion of public key from raw bytes (what `SecItemCopyMatching` gives you in dictionary under the kSecValueData) into PEM

```
+ (NSString*) openSSLPubKey:(NSData*) rawPublicKeyBytes {

  uint8_t curveOIDHeader[] = {0x30, 0x59, 0x30, 0x13, 0x06, 0x07, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0xCE, 0x3D, 0x02, 0x01, 0x06, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0xCE, 0x3D, 0x03, 0x01, 0x07, 0x03, 0x42, 0x00};

  NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:curveOIDHeader length:26];

  [data appendData:rawPublicKeyBytes];

  NSString* base64EncodedString = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength | NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n%@\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",base64EncodedString];

}
```

*Note that you can only store 256-bit elliptic curve private keys in the secure enclave, hence the hardcoded OID header*